# How to get dataframe with subset of records based on record criteria

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a new dataframe that is the subset of a larger dataframe for analysis.  Specifically, I want to return the most recent date from the larger dataframe for all names in the dataframe.

If my dataframe was the following:

```
Row Name Date  
1 Apples 2020-05-01 
2 Apples 2020-05-11
3 Apples 2020-05-21
4 Bananas 2020-05-11
5 Bananas 2020-05-21
6 Bananas 2020-05-31
```

I want to return the following:

```
3 A 2020-05-21
6 B 2020-05-31
```

I imagine the Pseudocode would be something like this:

```
df(new) = df(old)[df.Date == {most recent date for each name}]
```

Any help on this, or other longer code to subquery records/fields into a smaller dataframe would be appreciated.

Please let me know if further clarification is needed.  Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using :

```
# convert the date column to datetime
    df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
  
# create a new dataframe with only the columns  
    df1 = df.groupby('Name')['Date'].max().reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the most recent value, you may use `df.groupby().last()`

```
print(df)

   Name        Date
0   Apple  2020-05-01
1   Apple  2020-05-11
2   Apple  2020-05-21
3  Banana  2020-05-11
4  Banana  2020-05-21
5  Banana  2020-05-31

df.groupby("Name").last()
```

#### Output

```
              
Name          Date    
Apple   2020-05-21
Banana  2020-05-31
```

Comment: Thank you!  Can groupby be used for multiple conditions (say a column called "freshness" was added and the value "rotten" for all records with date <= 2020-05-12 and "fresh" was added for date > 2020-05-12; can groupby return the most recent record for each name and freshness)?  Just tried this myself without success.